# Stop Keyframe animation from automatic start on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, keyframe

I've got some css and Keyframe animations that I use to run a couple of Div elements. I want the css and keyframe animations only to start when i click my buttom. My problem is, they start on there own and then the animation-delay has run out and renders the button useless.

Here is the code I'm trying.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bt1").click(function(){
        $(".animation-box").addClass("first-text", "second-text", "third-text", "fourth-text", "fifth-text");
    });


    $('.animation-box').on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
         $(this).removeClass("first-text", "second-text", "third-text", "fourth-text", "fifth-text");
    });
});
```

```css
            @keyframes topFadeOut {
            0% {
                position: absolute;
                top: 10%;
                opacity: 0;
            }

            75% {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                opacity: 1;
            }

            100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            }

            @keyframes bottomFadeOut {
            0% {
                position: absolute;

                opacity: 0;
            }

            75% {
                position: absolute;

                opacity: 1;
            }

            100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            }

            @keyframes topFadeOutVertical {
            0% {
                position: absolute;
                top: 60%;
                opacity: 0;

            }

            75% {
                position: absolute;
                top: 65%;
                opacity: 1;

            }

            100% {
                opacity: 0;

            }
            }

            @keyframes rightFadeInOut {
            0% {
                position: absolute;
                right: -3rem;
                opacity: 0;

            }

            75% {
                position: absolute;
                right: 40%;
                opacity: 1;

            }

            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                right: 10rem;

            }
            }

            @keyframes fadeInOut {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;

            }

            45% {
                opacity: 1;

            }

            100% {
                opacity: 0%;

            }
            }

            .first-text {
            font-size: 4.4rem;
            position: absolute;
            left: 23%;
            top: 70%;
            opacity: 0;
            animation-name: topFadeOut;
            animation-duration: 5s;
            color: black;
            animation-play-state: i;
            }

            .second-text {
            font-size: 4.4rem;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            opacity: 0;
            animation-name: rightFadeInOut;
            animation-delay: 4s;
            animation-duration: 6s;
            color: black;
            animation-play-state: inherit;
            }

            .third-text {

            font-size: 4.4rem;
            position: absolute;
            left: 27%;
            top: 50%;
            opacity: 0;
            animation-name: topFadeOutVertical;
            animation-delay: 8s;
            animation-duration: 6s;
            color: black;
            white-space: nowrap;
            animation-play-state: inherit;
            }

            .fourth-text {
            font-size: 4.4rem;
            position: absolute;
            top: 55%;
            left: 27%;
            opacity: 0;
            color: black;
            animation-name: fadeInOut;
            animation-delay: 12s;
            animation-duration: 7s;
            animation-play-state: inherit;
            }

            .fifth-text {
            font-size: 5rem;
            position: absolute;
            left: 30%;
            top: 50%;
            opacity: 0;
            color: black;
            animation-name: bottomFadeOut;
            animation-delay: 16s;
            animation-duration: 9s;
            animation-play-state: inherit;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bt1" class="button button5">< R30K</button>
<button id="bt2" class="button button5">R30K - R70K</button>
<button id="bt3" class="button button5">> R70K</button>

<section class="animation-box">
    <div class="first-text">Starting winner selection process</div>
    <div class="second-text">Identifying eligible entries</div>
    <div class="third-text">Uploading eligible entries</div>
    <div class="fourth-text">Shuffling eligible entries</div>
    <div class="fifth-text">And the winner is...</div>
</section>
```

So when running that, the Keyframe animation starts on page load, causing me not to be able to use the button function.

What I want is to know how to stop keyframe from starting when page loads and to run the keyframe ONLY when button is clicked.

You're help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `animation-play-state` property to set the animation to paused initially

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Comment: When adding the animation-play-state: paused; to my .first-text{} etc. They button click doesn't work then.

Comment: Change your JS so instead of adding those classes, it changes the animation-play-state